# Gif images do not resize

Tags: sitecore

Running into a problem when the .gif images aren't resizing at all.

Ex: `/~/media/images/agifimage.gif?as=1&h=100&w=100` does not resize. Where as `/~/media/images/ajpegimage.jpeg?as=1&h=100&w=100` does resize.

I tried using .ashx extension as well with no help. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: This works for me on Sitecore 7.1, but only for not animated gif's. Do you use an animated gif? What version of Sitecore do you use?

Comment: Trying it out on 6.6 and yes non-animated gifs do not resize either for me.

Comment: Non-Animated Gif's also worked on Sitecore 6.6 for me. Do you have any special configuration for the media request handler or some other media configuration which is not original?

Comment: That's whats surprising to me. There is nothing custom going on. It can resize non-animated on my local environment though but not in QA. Checked/compared all config files and could not find any related differences.

Comment: Did you try reupload the gif? Maybe it is broken? Does other gif's work?

Comment: Same for all gif images. It's kinda weird. Some gif images I am able to scale up (with black borders) but never scale down.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your issue. I would suggest you creating an issue on the Sitecore Support Platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out some of the gif images where created using a tool that had their weird mime-type issue. When we try to use a different set of images, the re-sizing worked great. So if you experience this do try using other gif images.